# Any mantras that are not of Sanskrit origin?

Tags: philosophy, worship, mantras, sanskrit, prayer

Are there any spells (mantras) in Hinduism which are not in Sanskrit, but in other languages. I came across a mantra in Awadhi dialect of Hindi, it's something about blessings for studying and was devoted to Lord Rama! Do you know any other spell which is not in Sanskrit? Why can't we have spells in other languages? Any example?

Answer (score 8):

In South India,in the temples of the Lord Vishnu, the lord is often worshipped using tamil verses which were written by the great saints of Sri Vaishnavism Azhwars.Most important and famous one is the **Thiruppavai** which was written by **Sri Aandaal(maiden name"Godha devi")**.Thiruppavai is recited in almost all vishnu temples in the month of Dhanurmasa in the place of suprabhaatham.There are plenty of traditional works of azhwars that are chanted in Vaishnava temples during different occasions.

Comment: I assume that you understand tamil.Can u then please tell us the exact meanings of the the Mantras in my answer?

Comment: @Rickross I am a Srivaishnava.So I know the texts I said in my answer.I don't understand Tamil.But the mantras you depicted in your answer are more like slogans.1.Hail Mahaganapathi.2.Hail lord Shiva(shiva perumal)perumal means god in tamil.Likewise they are more like slogans given by folk people and not the priests in the temples.

Comment: Ok.The mantras that are in my answers are said to be mantras given to this world by the Siddhas.they don't need initiation and can be chanted by anyone.It is said that one great Siddha(can't recall his name) was once roaming in a jungle and it is then that these mantras are revealed to him from nowhere.

Answer (score 6):

I know of few mantras which are in Tamil.
They are siddha mantras(given by the siddhas).Few examples are as below:

Ganapaty-Om mahaganapatikku harohara.
Parasakti-Om Parasktikku Harohara
Shiva-Om Shiva Perumanukku harohara...and  similar mantras for many other Gods.

**Edit**-I'm adding the source which contains the whole list of such Mantras.Also adding a few more of these Mantras for some important Deities.

> MahaGanapati-Ohm Maha Ganapathiku Arohara
>
> Shiva-Ohm Sivaperumanuku Arohara.
>
> Vishnu-Ohm Vishnuperumanuku Arohara.
>
> Parashakti-Ohm Parasakthiku Arohara.
>
> Brahma-Ohm Birumma Devanuku Arohara.
>
> Asta Lakshmi-Ohm Astalakshmikaluku Arohara.
>
> Saraswati-Ohm Kalaivaniku Arohara.
>
> Skanda(Murugan)-Ohm Murugapperumanuku Arohara.
>
> Navagraha-Ohm Navakiraha Nayagarkaluku Arohara.

But,since i don't know tamil i don't know the exact meanings of the Mantras.It will be nice if someone who knows tamil can explain the exact meanings of the words that are being used in these Mantras.

[Source](http://www.nandhi.com/nandhi/ancient-learning-2/invoke-siddhars-2/)

Comment: But that sound Sanskrit!

Comment: Only Om is sanskrit,rest is in tamil,

Comment: I dont know if its similar to the one i heard but if its same, then its like hailing names of all 210 siddhas. Story goes like a siddha was walking through forest to mountain, where he heard this.

Comment: Yes you are right. That's how he got all these many mantras @Rudra

Answer (score 4):

Certainly there are non sanskrit mantras as well. If you look at Natha sampradaya, they have tradition of [Shabara mantras](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101129213818AA3KJRd) which contain hindi, sadhukkadi, avadhi, and urdu words in addition to sanskrit words.

After all mantras are based on the intention, concentration and belief of the chanter and based on the sound rather than any specific language.

There are many folk tales and tradition which talk of non sanskrit mantras. In kerela too there is a section called Kerela mantrikan which has non sanskrit mantras. In some tribal population we do find mantras or spells of different language.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! On this site we have to provide  sources from authentic Hindu scriptures in the answer.Pls. provide some sources in your answer.Unsourced answers might get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer this question simply because the word "Mantra" in itself is too broad, in my opinion.

First of all, lets try to understand what is meaning of Mantra.

Mantra(मंत्र) is a sacred utterance believed by practitioners to have psychological and spiritual powers. 
The Sanskrit word [mantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantra) consists of the root man- "to think" (also in manas "mind") and the suffix -tra, designating tools or instruments, hence a literal translation would be "instrument of thought".

> So, Mantra(मंत्र) = instrument of thought

Next, these Mantra comes in many different forms. For example: verses from the Rigveda or musical chants from the Sāmaveda can be considered as Mantra.

Beside this, there is [no formal definition of Mantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantra#Definition).

Considering all above points, its hard to prove or disprove what is Mantra and what is NOT a Mantra.

Now, to answer the question, there is  [Maruti Stotra](http://www.indif.com/nri/marathi_prayers/marathi_stotras/maruti_stotra.asp) written in Marathi, which is popular in Maharashtra India.

Other popular example is [Hanuman Chalisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman_Chalisa) written in Awadhi language.

These both can be considered as  stotra (and not Mantra) but one can use either whole or some verse inside it, as an "**instrument of thought**".

And hence it can be termed as Mantra.