# Do I need diksha for shabar mantra as like Vedic or tantrik mantra?

Tags: mantras

Our scriptures say One needs to get initation from a Guru to chant one particular mantra. It's for vedic Or tantrik mantras. But do we need diksha for sadhana of shabar mantra also? I have heard that shabar mantra is sidh mantras. So I am bit confused about it.

Comment: What is shabar mantra?

Comment: [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17115/17833) @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: Related post -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17510/4732

Comment: Shabar mantras are Siddha alright but they might still require initiation but not fully sure about this.